# how to denote function arguments in python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I need to print following info using unnecessary argument (**track**):

```
def make_album(singer, album, track = ''):
  album = {'singer_name' : singer, 'slbum' : album}

  if track:
    album['track'] = track
    return album

output = make_album('Linkin Park',  'October')
print(output)  
output = make_album('Lara Fabian',  'Ju\'tem', 13)
print(output)  
output = make_album('Space Girls',  'Viva')
print(output)
```

But the output is kind of

```
None
{'singer_name': 'Lara Fabian', 'slbum': "Ju'tem", 'track': 13}
None
```

How to denote args to avoid **none** output

Comment: Your indentation for the return statement means that it only executes, if track...

Answer (score 3):

you have a return in your function only if your `track` argument is not an empty string otherwise your function returns `None` to fix you can use:

```
def make_album(singer, album, track = ''):
  album = {'singer_name' : singer, 'slbum' : album}

  if track:
    album['track'] = track
  return album
```